# Stream lit histogram with multiple arrays with different rows each

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, streamlit

I am trying to create a histogram in streamlit using plotly distplot.
My data is as below, where each array has different number of rows and the range of values is same for all the 3 arrays (0-100). However, since the bin size is same, the visualization get overlapped.

```
import streamlit as st
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x1 = np.random.uniform(0,100,(1000))
x2 = np.random.uniform(0,100,(2000))
x3 = np.random.uniform(0,100,(3000))    
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3]
group_labels = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, bin_size=[10, 10, 10, 10])
fig.show()
```

Can someone please help me with how to achieve this?

Comment: What is your expected output? How would you avoid the distributions overlapping if they are very similar?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your question but,  I suggest you to hide the bins/hist and the rug to see easily the graph.

```
x1 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (1000))
x2 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (2000))
x3 = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (3000))   
 
hist_data = [x1, x2, x3]
group_labels = ['Group1','Group2','Group3']

figejemplo = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, 
                             bin_size=[10, 10, 10, 10], show_hist=False, show_rug=False)

st.plotly_chart(figejemplo, config=config, use_container_width=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for, however, how the y-axis here is normalized, what if I want the actual values of the array?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. In fact, it is a density plot but, it is very functional as well.